# How to release a python program to user

Tags: python, anaconda, release-management, software-distribution

I have developed a python program by anaconda as my development environment. How can I package my python program (let say it is just 1 .py file now) and distribute to user's PC for them to run?

Comment: You looking for something like: py2exe?

Comment: No, i am thinking how to deliver the python without converting to exe in this question. Is it converting to exe the only way to release to user PC?

Comment: pip+github is good if they have a github and can use a terminal

Comment: @palazzotrain it depends on how competent the users are.  Max said PIP and GITHUB is a great way to get some code in place and create a module or egg file.  If you want the entire thing to be self contained in 1 file that is built for non-computationally competent individuals, packaging python and all the dependancies into an exe is a solid approach.

Comment: @Fallenreaper, yes i am targeting to non-computationally competent individuals. But another problem is I don't want to install other package like py2exe (if possible) because my company has a very strict control to software installation. I have anaconda installed already on my PC, how can I utilize it and make a simple package ?

Comment: If the software (*.py) is for end users and they are non-developers, then it is btter to share your python file with FTP or  network share.

Comment: what does the program do? it might be possible to host it somewhere (possibly on your own machine) and have the users interact through a web ui. python is not very friendly for distributing/creating self-contained executables unfortuantely, it's one of the major weaknesses of the language.

Comment: the program just reads a file (also provide by me) and then output some text.

Answer (score 8):

use pyinstaller:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

and then:

```
pyinstaller -F mycript.py
```

Comment: this looks very interesting, never seen it

Comment: @palazzotrain if you dont want to use py2exe, pyinstaller works too.  Granted, pip install does install the pyinstaller but that might be able to circumvent the normal "installing an exe" kind of approach

Comment: py2exe only works for windows.as a mac user,I prefer pyinstaller :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can follow the step of the pages:

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/packaging/

https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.io/

Make a script in `setup.py`; upload your package; let your users install by `pip`
Then use it.